# Kubuntu 20.04 lost sddm display

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, sddm

I've avoided posting this question for a month while I tried to find out on my own what had gone wrong, but now there is no other recourse.

After running Kubuntu 20.04 for about a year on a desktop (with / on a 60 GB SSD), suddenly one day a routine reboot never yielded a full desktop display -- only a konsole window (with full decorations) that worked fine for command-line activities, apparently because I had set it up to log me in automatically on reboot.  I used it to #apt install --reinstall everything I could find that might be related to sddm, to no effect.  I tried running kubuntu directly off the DVD; that works fine, but didn't seem like an acceptable conclusion.  Finally I gave up and reinstalled the system from DVD on the same SSD.  It worked fine until I ran #apt upgrade and rebooted, at which point it reverted to the same nonfunctioning sddm.  I tried removing sddm and installing gdm3; that was a total failure.  I concluded that my SSD must be faulty, so I replaced it with a HD and reinstalled again.  Same result after #apt upgrade, except of course lots slower now.

So it APPEARS that there is something amiss in the latest version of something that sddm relies upon.  But surely that situation would not persist for a MONTH!  I am now installing "vanilla" Ubuntu 20.04 in (faint) hopes of a better result.  Next step will be a different distro entirely.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have *autologin* enabled, I'd ensure you are running the KDE Plasma desktop, as for example you may be using something simple like `openbox` (used as example only) which has no panel, no obvious desktop visible, which would be fixed by logging out and selecting a different desktop to be used (the autologin causing either the last used, which isn't plasma anymore, or you made something else the default).  *I'm using `openbox` as example as it's installed by default with Lubuntu, you may have something else as a WM or DE in either last-used or default*

Comment: As soon as I gave up and decided to reinstall, I ditched autologin; then I didn't even get the konsole window after the first reboot.  Ubuntu 20.04 installation (with gdm3 instead of sddm) gave exactly the same behaviour.  Next I'll try Open SuSE....

Comment: Sounds to me it was a user config issue, thus the DM, WM or DE in use will be impacted by the same user config files. I use debian bullseye/sid, ubuntu hirsute, fedora (rawhide) & opensuse (tumbleweed) & differences are very few between them (outside of package versions as some are more *modern* and others *behind)...   I believe it's not a Ubuntu/sddm issue, but user created/config issue.  (from your description)